# Prevent variable expansion in Bash heredocument

Tags: bash, heredoc, variable-expansion

I would like to create a **longer** multiline string in Bash **without variable expansion**. This text contains also items like `${varname}` which is expanded according to the specification. However, I don't want to expand them in my script.

```
Dockerfile=`cat <<____
ARG BUILD_IMAGE
FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE}
...
# lots of further lines
____
`
```

I tried several variants (`$\{`, `$\0173`), but I could only solve it with

```
b='${'
...
FROM ${b}BUILD_IMAGE}
...
```

Which is really ugly. Is there any better way to solve this?

**Edit**:

```
Dockerfile=`cat <<'____'
ARG BUILD_IMAGE
FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE}
...
# lots of further lines
____
`
```

would solve the issue, but in this case I can't use any variable expansion.

**Edit 2 - Answer**:

Since the post has been closed, I answer my question here:

There is a difference between using backquote and `$(`. **The issue is solved if I use the latter one.** I had the problem, because I used the former one.

> When  the  old-style  backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
> retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `,  or  .   The
> first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command sub‐
> stitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between  the
> parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

This means in praxis:

```
text=$(cat <<__EOT__
Hello ${who}, hello \${who}!
__EOT__
)
echo $text

text=`cat <<__EOT__
Hello ${who}, hello \${who}!
__EOT__
`
echo $text
```

results in

```
Hello World, hello ${who}!
Hello World, hello World!
```

Comment: That's a here document, not a here string (those use `<<<` syntax).

Comment: You can embed newlines in a simple single-quoted string; you don't really need to use `cat`.

Comment: @chepner, the question is not about new lines. It is about variable expansion. In a longer text. I emphasized the question.

Comment: They are trying to say you don't need a here document for this simple assignment. Just assign the variable with newlines between the single quotes.

Comment: @FERcsI That's why I commented, rather than answering. The question is more or less moot.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the answer. The text, which I have not copied here has 20-30 lines, so heredoc is a better choice (I've been using bash for 2 decades, but not every day). I am searching for an escape sequence instead of `$b`, but I am afraid of not having any.
cat << '____' would also solve the problem, but in that case none of the variables are expanded.

Comment: @chepner, which, according to this, was not clear, that I have a longer text, where heredoc looks to be the best choice for me (without having extra files).
And I can solve this issue in multiple (not really nice) ways, but I would like to learn if there are a nice solution for escaping in here.

Comment: I added a few more duplicates which discuss various aspects of this. The last one has an answer of mine which demonstrates `printf` where you could then single-quote most lines, but selectively double-quote a few where you need to.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the extra info. I could figure out, that backtick behaves differently from `$(`, which is actually documented. So
`text=\`cat <<_EOT_` Is different from
`text=$(cat <<_EOT_`
And I need this latter. I thought they are the same, until now.

Comment: @chepner The references you sent me were helpful to find the final issue, but none of them contained the answer, so **I consider my question a new one**. Including my answer. I suggest to reopen it for others to learn from it.